# How can I use NSE and filter an expression using ... (ellipsis)?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

How can I utilize the magic dots (...) / ellipsis in order to filter based off an arbitrary column?

```
df = tibble::tibble(col1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'), col2 = c(1,3,4))

my_func = function(x, ...){
  df %>%
    dplyr::filter(... == x)
}

my_func('a', col1)


# Should return:
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  col1   col2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
```

Comment: You usually want to pass a data frame as the first argument to a `dplyr`-type function. Try switching the arguments to `dataframe, string, ...`. Also `...` implies multiple columns being possible—how do you want to do with the comparison when you have more than one column coming in?

Comment: That's certainly very true, this was a specific use case in a legacy code base. I have to chip away at it and this is basically a stepping stone as I being to refactor. It will certainly move to having a variable name rather than `...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We  can convert to a quosure (`quo`) and evaluate (`!!`).  Here, we assume there would be only a single column passed into the `filter`

```
my_func <- function(x, ...){
   df %>%
      dplyr::filter(!! quo(...) == x)
  }



my_func('a', col1)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  col1   col2
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a         1
```

If there are multiple columns, then it may be better to use `filter_at`

---

It may be also better to make use of `{{}}` if we can pass as an argument instead of `...`

```
my_func <- function(x, coln) {
        df %>%
              filter({{coln}} == x)
    }
my_func('a', col1)
```